# Install Google cloud sdk on aws ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, installation, cloud

I am trying to install Google cloud sdk on EC2 instance and I am getting a forbidden error:

Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!

To help improve the quality of this product, we collect anonymized usage data
and anonymized stacktraces when crashes are encountered; additional information
is available at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/usage-statistics. You may choose
to opt out of this collection now (by choosing 'N' at the below prompt), or at
any time in the future by running the following command:

```
gcloud config set disable_usage_reporting true

Do you want to help improve the Google Cloud SDK (Y/n)?  n

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 214, in <module>
  main()
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 192, in main
  Install(pargs.override_components, pargs.additional_components)
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 138, in Install
  _CLI.Execute(['--quiet', 'components', 'list'])
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 734, in Execute
  self._HandleAllErrors(exc, command_path_string, specified_arg_names)
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 712, in Execute
  resources = args.calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 786, in Run
  display_info=self.ai.display_info).Display()
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\display.py", line 424, in Display

  self._printer.Print(self._resources)
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\resource\resource_printer_base.py", line 251, in Print
  for resource in resources:
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\components\list.py", line 86, in Run
  result = update_manager.List()
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 519,
in List
  _, diff =  self._GetStateAndDiff(command_path='components.list')
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 448,
in _GetStateAndDiff
  command_path=command_path)
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 431,
in _GetLatestSnapshot
  *effective_url.split(','), command_path=command_path)
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\snapshots.py", line 165, in FromURLs
  for url in urls]
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\snapshots.py", line 186, in _
DictFromURL
  response = installers.ComponentInstaller.MakeRequest(url, command_path)
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\installers.py", line 285, in
MakeRequest
  return ComponentInstaller._RawRequest(req, timeout=timeout)
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\installers.py", line 329, in
_RawRequest
  should_retry_if=RetryIf, sleep_ms=500)
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\retry.py", line 155, in TryFunc
  return func(*args, **kwargs), None
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\url_opener.py", line 73, in urlopen
  return opener.open(req, data, timeout)
File "c:\users\awsglo~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgynube\python\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "c:\users\awsglo~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgynube\python\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
  '_open', req)
File "c:\users\awsglo~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgynube\python\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\url_opener.py", line 58, in https_open
  return self.do_open(build, req)
File "c:\users\awsglo~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgynube\python\lib\urllib2.py", line 1194, in do_open
  h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
File "c:\users\awsglo~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgynube\python\lib\httplib.py", line 1053, in request
  self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "c:\users\awsglo~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgynube\python\lib\httplib.py", line 1093, in _send_request
  self.endheaders(body)
File "c:\users\awsglo~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgynube\python\lib\httplib.py", line 1049, in endheaders
  self._send_output(message_body)
File "c:\users\awsglo~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgynube\python\lib\httplib.py", line 893, in _send_output
  self.send(msg)
File "c:\users\awsglo~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgynube\python\lib\httplib.py", line 855, in send
  self.connect()
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1055, in connect
  sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\socks\__init__.py", line 442, in connect
  self.__negotiatehttp(destpair[0], destpair[1])
File "F:\Source\software\google-cloud-sdk-155.0.0-windows-x86_64-bundled-python\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\socks\__init__.py", line 406, in __negotiatehttp
  raise HTTPError((statuscode, statusline[2]))
***socks.HTTPError: (403, 'Forbidden')***
Google Cloud SDK installer will now exit.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Any feedback...?

Comment: Please let me know if we need to whitelist any url in our AWS environment to install Google Cloud SDK

Comment: There is no URL blacklist or filtering imposed by EC2's infrastructure.  Your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44414838/1695906) is redundant and should be deleted.

Comment: Have you tried this on a different EC2 instance?  How about outside of EC2?  Does your instance have outbound Internet access?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed Google cloud sdk on ec2, i did not face any url issue you can try by reinstalling it if in case it is not installed:-
you can perform below steps
Steps to uninstall 
1)Locate your installation directory by running:
    gcloud info --format='value(installation.sdk_root)'
    gcloud info --format='value(config.paths.global_config_dir)'
    note the directory to delete
2)Delete both these directories.

Steps to install:-
1)curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash
2)restart shell 
exec -l $SHELL
3) link account
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$PATH TO KEY FILE
4)gcloud init (please make proper selection as per your requirement)
5) After above steps try running gsutil ls OR bq ls command and see if buckets and datasets are listed properly.

After performing all above steps successfully,gcloud sdk and installed and working successfully in ec2.

Comment: what is the key file? should i have in my google account?